# When I restart I don't see GRUB and go straight to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have installed ubuntu alongside windows xp, but cannot get to my ubuntu operating system... and go  straight to windows every time.

I have tried to reinstal ubuntu, but the DVD doesn't recognise any operating system on my hard drive.

I then ran "try ubuntu" ... and did a boot repair.  This is the result:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6602565/

Here is what came out of fdisk

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
omitting empty partition (5)

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x41ab2316

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63      176714       88326   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *      176715   147990779    73907032+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       147990780   305652689    78830955    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4       300415563   305652689     2618563+  dd  Unknown
/dev/sda5       147990906   294118019    73063557   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       294118083   300415499     3148708+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 1):

The windows partition has the boot flag set. Boot in live CD, open the program Gparted, select sda5 (ubuntu partition) and right click and say manage flags. Select boot.

Now take out the CD and restart. You should get the GRUB menu where you can pick windows or ubuntu.

If something is wrong with ubuntu and this still doesn't work you can undo this by loading in live CD and putting the boot flag back to sda2 where it was.

**Terminal method**
This has been added as there seems to be a problems getting gparted to see the disk.

Boot in Live CD again and run

```
fdisk -l
```

Just to check nothing has changed. For you your linux partition with the grub files is sda5 (**NOTE anyone else who finds this make sure you know which partition grub is on before running a command like this**) So we run

```
sudo parted /dev/sda set 5 boot on
```

Now restart, and it should hopefully work. I want to warn you that if your linux boot is broken this could just cause no booting at all. In which case you again boot in live CD and can undo it with:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda set 2 boot on
```

Comment: Dear Julian, I did per your suggestion, but when in GParted I only see one partition... and that says "unalocated"?

Comment: That is worrying! You don't even see the windows partition? What does it tell you the size of this unallocated device is? t is worth checking you aren't somehow looking at another drive (the CD?). In the top right corner there should be a little box with a picture of a drive saying something like /dev/sda. Click that. Are there any more options?

Comment: I do think that Gparted is only seeing the CD (under view, I get the info of the CD player).  The right hand corner does say /dev/sda, and has a size if 149.05 GB .. but no more options are indicated.

Comment: No chance you could screenshot Gparted for me? Also in the file browser can you see your partitions for mounting? Also if you could run `sudo fdisk -l` and paste the output somewhere that would be useful.

Comment: In file browser I can see the partitions!  I ran fdisk too, and this also lists the partitions.  I have taken the screenshot but can't see how to send it to you?

Comment: Click edit on your post and then on the img option (I am not sure if this requires reputation) if you can't do that upload to any image sharing site and post a link. Also post a copy of what comes out of fdisk -l in the original post by editing (It should be the same as from pastebin but I don't want to give the wrong command to change the boot from terminal, so lets be safe!!)

Comment: Post updated again

Comment: I just tried the command "sudo parted /dev/sda set 5 boot on" after checking with fdisk, but I get the error "can't have overlapping partitions"

Comment: Urg. If I was you I would start another new questioned something like: "Can't see partition table in Gparted, error 'can't have overlapping partitions'". Post the fdisk output from above. Along with an explanation of what you have tried. Hopefully get someone who has seen this before to help. It is "out of my league", sorry!

Comment: Julian.. I appreciate your efforts ... and will post another question as you say above!